# Bold & normal text in ListView items

Tags: android, listview, text, bold

I am looking to create a list with a format looking something like this:

**Sensor 1**

var1=4, var2=4

---

**Sensor 2**

var1=2, var2=-12

---

So I would like to have a bold header, and then some other info on a separate line in each item in the list. This is how I am currently adding things to my list.

```
View sensorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensor, container, false);
                ListView sensorList = (ListView)sensorView.findViewById(R.id.sensorList);
                String [] sensors = {"Sensor2\nAlpha=2", "Sensor3\nAlpha=2"};
                ListAdapter sensorListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensors);
                sensorList.setAdapter(sensorListAdapter);
```

I've tried using Html.fromhtml() but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: i would suggest you to use recycler view instead

Comment: RecyclerView is much more flexible than ListView, i reckon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom adapter view to replace android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 that has two TextView views, one for the header and one for the content.  Then just override the ArrayAdapter class to set the text to each view.

Example: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)